# How to setup another username in database?

Tags: postgresql, typescript, knex.js, koa, objection.js

I'am a newbie frontend trainee, and I have a task to configure my project on node-typescript-koa-rest. I tried to do my best to configure it, but it has an error.

First of all, I get this project, https://github.com/javieraviles/node-typescript-koa-rest, add here objection.js, knex.js, installed postgresql. After starting my project, I recieve an "TypeORM connection error:  error: password authentication failed for user "user" ". From error message I can't get where username for db sets.

On start script.ts is running.
https://pastebin.com/fm0TBaXQ
Where I can change username and password?

Full error message:

```
TypeORM connection error:  error: password authentication failed for user "user"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/valentin/Projects/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/valentin/Projects/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:19)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/valentin/Projects/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:203:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:276:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:210:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17) {
  name: 'error',
  length: 100,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '328',
  routine: 'auth_failed'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the `databaseUrl` setting in the [config.ts](https://github.com/javieraviles/node-typescript-koa-rest/blob/master/src/config.ts) file.